# Разный контент страницы при обновлении

Tags: php, css, javascript

Привет народ.
Есть лендинг с двумя однотипными подстраницами (так сказать), имеющие разный бекграунд. Необходимо соединить их в одну, чтобы при обновлении пользователем менялся фон. Как реализовать? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пишем CSS стили:

.wrap{
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
}
.bg-1{
    background: red;
}
.bg-2{
    background: blue;
}

на страничке пишем:
<div class="wrap bg-<?= rand(1, 2) ?>">

Comment: А ежили не рандомно, а последовательно?

Comment: на кукисах, вывод примерно такой <div class="wrap bg-<?= $_COOKIE['bg'] ?>">
но с начало нужно  куки записать требуемое значение

Comment: самый простой вариант записать куки можно так (вставить перед html):
switch($_COOKIE['bg']){
    case 1: SetCookie('bg', 2);break;
    case 2: SetCookie('bg', 1);break;
    default: SetCookie('bg', 1);
}

Comment: но лучше куки записывать с помощью javascript